# can`t link mongo docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have an image (`gepick:latest`) with `node` app created from `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM centos:7

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
RUN yum install -y nodejs
RUN curl --silent --location https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/yarn.repo | tee /etc/yum.repos.d/yarn.repo
RUN rpm --import https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/pubkey.gpg
RUN yum install -y yarn
RUN yarn

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "yarn", "test-matches-collecting-job"]
```

My goal is run tests in docker. But it requires `mongodb`

`docker run gepick:latest` :

```
...
Mongoose default connection error: MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
...
```

I tried link `mongo:4` images container `docker run --link 0d24c3a35d5a gepick:latest` but get same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you launch your container using a docker-compose yaml file Docker bridges the containers together and allows you to have it launch the mongo container before other containers which rely on mongo to be active ... try something like this

cat my-docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:

  my-gepick:
    image: gepick:latest
    container_name: blah_gepick
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - loudmongo
    volumes:
      - /cryptdata5/var/log/blobs:/blobs
      - /webapp/enduser/bundle:/tmp
    environment:
      - MONGO_SERVICE_HOST=loudmongo
      - MONGO_SERVICE_PORT=$GKE_MONGO_PORT
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://loudmongo:$GKE_MONGO_PORT/test
      - METEOR_SETTINGS=${METEOR_SETTINGS}
      - MAIL_URL=smtp://support@${GKE_DOMAIN_NAME}:blah@loudmail:587/
    links:
      - loudmongo
    ports:
     - 127.0.0.1:3000:3000
    working_dir: /tmp
    command: /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

  loudmongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: loud_mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
     - 127.0.0.1:$GKE_MONGO_PORT:$GKE_MONGO_PORT
    volumes:
     - /cryptdata7/var/data/db:/data/db
```

so your launch sequence may look like

```
docker-compose -f /somedir/my-docker-compose.yml pull 
docker-compose -f /somedir/my-docker-compose.yml up -d
```